# Проблема с правами при загрузки файла через php форму

Tags: apache, nginx, php, fileupload

Здравствуйте, есть код:

```
 $id= rand();
 mkdir ("share/$id");
 chmod ("share/$id", 777);

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "share/$id/".$name);
```

Этот код выдает ошибку:

> Warning:
> move_uploaded_file(share/34602835/search4.jpg):
> failed to open stream: Permission
> denied in ...
> on line 24 Warning:
> move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
> '/tmp/phpKC0e0Y' to
> 'share/34602835/search4.jpg' in
> ...
> on line 24

24 строка это:
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "share/$id/".$name);

Из-за чего такая ошибка?

На сервере nginx, как фронт энд к апачу. Все скрипты работают, кроме этого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался.

```
chmod ("share/$id", 777);
```

Вместо этого надо:

```
chmod ("share/$id", 0777);
```